# Why does adding padding to an img leave a border in the image, yet padding on a div does not when using CSS background URL?

Tags: html, css

Why does this using the `img` tag force a white border?  I've tried `border:0;` with but a white border is still there in the picture.  This does not happen when you use `div` though. And is there anyway to get rid of it? See my example below:

```css
div {
        background: url("https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg");
        width: 100px;
        height: 150px;
        padding: 10px;
}

    .image {
        background: url("https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg");
        width: 100px;
        height: 150px;
        padding: 10px;
    }
```

```html
<img class="image">
<br>
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is simple, you are wrongly using the `img` tag because:

> src
>
> The image URL. Mandatory for the  element

And

> If an error occurs while loading or rendering an image, and an onerror event handler has been set on the error event, that event handler will get called. This can happen in a number of situations, including:
>
> - The src attribute is empty ("") or null.

<sup>https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img</sup>

So you are falling into the error case where the browser will decide to output *something* related to the error that you cannot really control.

If you add `alt` you will get another output:

```css
div {
  background: url("https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg");
  width: 100px;
  height: 150px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.image {
  background: url("https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg");
  width: 100px;
  height: 150px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<img class="image" alt="image">
<br>
<div></div>
```

I don't see the purpose of doing this with `img` but if you insist on placing a background image inside consider having a valid `url` of an image. Even an empty SVG will do it

```css
div {
  background: url("https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg");
  width: 100px;
  height: 150px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.image {
  background: url("https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg");
  width: 100px;
  height: 150px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<img class="image" src="data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'></svg>" alt="image">
<br>
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why would you want to set a background image for an `img` element? For an `img` element, you could just use the `src` attribute instead to set its image. (I fail to see the need for setting an image's background image.)

So for rendering images, I would personally:

- Use an `img` element and set the (required!) `src` attribute. This would be my preference if the image is part of the web page's (dynamic) functional/informational content. It would be included when copying/pasting data from the web site.
- Use a `div` element with a CSS background image. This would be my preference if the image is part of the web page's (static) design. It would be ignored when copying/pasting data from the web site.

```css
.background-image {
    background: url("https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg");
    width: 100px;
    height: 150px;
    padding: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box; /* do not size by content, but by border */
}

.image {
    object-fit: none; /* do not resize image */
    object-position: left top; /* do not center image */
    width: 100px;
    height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<img class="image" src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg">
<br>
<div class="background-image"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using `border: 0;`, use `border: none;`.

You can also try using `box-sizing: border-box;` to set the padding and margin inside of the element so that the total width/height is the exact total instead of having to add borders, padding, and margin to the equation.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing#:~:text=border%2Dbox%20tells%20the%20browser,to%20absorb%20that%20extra%20width.

> border-box tells the browser to account for any border and padding in
>   the values you specify for an element's width and height. If you set
>   an element's width to 100 pixels, that 100 pixels will include any
>   border or padding you added, and the content box will shrink to absorb
>   that extra width.